# Clear the the local storage data when navigate to another route from current route

Tags: angular

I want a component to remove `local storage` and `navigate` to another component while navigating using route path change.

Please find the `stack blitz`, after navigating from X to Y, then come back to X, it should remove local storage. But its reverse.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxmstz

Below is what I want to achieve,

I have a page where I am storing one value in `local storage`. If I refresh the page, I should get the value from local storage, which is happening. If I navigate to another page then I should clear the local storage. Because of "some reasons" I am using the **same key** to store the value in local storage in another component"s" as well.

I cleared the local storage in `ngDestroy`, but if I navigate to another route by changing the url then `ngdestory` is not calling (because both are in same router outlet), so my local storage is not removing.

If I use `@HostListener('window:beforeunload')` on top of `ngDestory` then when I refresh the page then also `ngDestroy` is executing and my local storage is getting removed. which I didn't want.

> 1/ Page X -> Store Local Storage -> Refresh -> fetch from local
>   storage and show
>
> 2/ website url route change from x to y -> need to remove local
>   storage and go to Y.

If I remove local storage in Y's ngOnInit then Y also having the same functionality, so Y will lose its local storage value if refresh happens on Y.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular's interface `CanActivate`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
            if (next && next.routeConfig && next.routeConfig.path ) {
            //your logic here
            localStorage.removeItem('myItem');//to clear specific Item
            localStorage.clear();//to entirely clear local storage
            }
    }
}
```

All you need to do is create one service in your angular project and refer above implementation of the `CanActivate.`

Comment: Thanks Vinod,If I refresh the page, the local storage value should be available. will this code be still valid in this scenario?

Comment: yes, local storage is stored in browser. so if you refresh the page the value will be there unless it get cleared or overridden manually.

Comment: Hi vinod,  i m incorpodating the change, because my localstorage object is bit complex, sure i will mark, please wait. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could solve it like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<button [routerLink]="['/x-dashboard']">X Dashboard</button>
<button [routerLink]="['/y-dashboard']">Y Dashboard</button>
<router-outlet #outlet="outlet" (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

onActivate(event) {
    if(localStorage.getItem('lastPage') !== this.route.firstChild.snapshot.routeConfig.path){
        console.log('clearStorage');
        localStorage.clear;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('lastPage', this.route.firstChild.snapshot.routeConfig.path);
  }
```

Comment: I dont want this logic to be written in all the pages

Comment: This logic only needs to be added to the AppComponent. Whenever a route changes it will be executed.